# Do Spherical Lenses Have Circle Symmetry?

Tags: symmetry, isometry, spherical-geometry

For the purposes of this question, a *spherical lens* is the interesection of two spherical half-spaces in $\mathbb{S}^3$. (A *spherical half-space* is the intersection of $\mathbb{S}^3$ with a half-space in $\mathbb R^4$ whose boundary contains the origin.) My question is:

> Is there an action of $S^1$ on $\mathbb{S}^3$ by isometries that preserves a given spherical lens?

I feel like the answer should be yes, but my intuition is very Euclidean and the coordinates are too dense for my liking. Topologically, the two spherical half-spaces are 3-balls, so their boundaries are 2-spheres, interesecting in a circle. The spheres have the same radius, so the lens is symmetric. If I try to picture this in $\mathbb R^3$, I can see that there is a line passing through the centres of the top and bottom faces, and any rotation about this line preserves the lens. But this is a Euclidean rotation in $\mathbb R^3$—does a similar 'rotation' exist for $\mathbb{S}^3$?

Comment: I'm trying to get the right picture here, because this construction seems odd to me. Let's say a $3$-spherical lens is what you described, where $3$ refers to $\mathbb S^3$ and $\mathbb R^{(3+1)}$. I'm not sure I understand your definition of spherical half-space. Would a $2$-spherical lens be the intersection of two surfaces with boundary given by the formulas $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = 1$ and $c(x-a) + d(x-b) + e \ge 0$ (or in other words, some half-space passing through the origin of the sphere)?

Comment: Because a $2$-spherical lens is basically a partial circle (the intersection of two spheres is a circle, so the intersection of two half-spheres would just be part of that circle). So I wouldn't be surprised if a $3$-spherical lens was a partial sphere.

Comment: A 2-spherical lens would be the intersection of two hemispheres, *with the same radius and centre*. Its boundary would be two great semicircles, intersecting at a pair of antipodal points, with some angle in $(0,\pi]$. You can think of a 3-spherical lens as the intersection of two 'hemi-3-spheres' (this would be another term for spherical half-spaces), with the same radius and centre. Its boundary is two 'great hemispheres', intersecting along a great circle, with some angle in $(0,\pi]$.

Comment: A more common term for a 2-spherical lens is a 'bigon' or 'lune'.

Comment: If the two half-spaces are defined by normal vectors $n_1$ and $n_2$, then the lens has symmetry of rotation in the plane perpendicular to $n_1$ and $n_2$